# How do change the RBS Threshold?

Tags: rbs, sql-server-2014

We are using SQL Server 2014 and SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the minimum BLOB storage size for each content database from the default size of 5 MB:

Start the SharePoint Management Shell.
At the Windows PowerShell command prompt, type the following commands to modify the minimum BLOB storage size to 1MB.

```
$cdb=get-SPContentDatabase ContentDatabaseName
$cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings.MinimumBlobStorageSize=1048576
$cdb.Update()

iisreset -noforce
```

Reference: [Modifying the Minimum BLOB Storage Size](https://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/article?p=18052.htm)

You also need to have a look at Shredded Storage Chunk Size (also known as FileWriteChunkSize). The FileWriteChunkSize must always be greater than MinimumBlobStorageSize. If this rule is broken, no content will get externalized!

FileWriteChunkSize gets configured at WebApplication level (example: 2MB):

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication http://yourwebappurl
$webapp.WebService.FileWriteChunkSize = 2097152 
$webapp.webservice.Update()
```

Reference: [SharePoint Storage Optimization: Why Shredded Storage and Remote Blob Storage are Better Together](https://www.avepoint.com/blog/avepoint-blog/sharepoint-optimization-shredded-storage/)